# How can I make this batch file check if x process is running, and then kill y process when x process stops running?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

```
@echo off
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq munt.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "munt.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" goto :EOF
cd "Sound\VST MIDI Synth\MT-32 VST\"
start /min "" munt.exe
ping -n 2 -w 1000 127.0.0.1 >nul
```

Basically, once this batch file is initiated (by running a program), I want it to kill munt.exe if dosbox.exe is terminated. I've tried various solutions but I don't think I'm getting the syntax right. Any help is appreciated!

Additionally, I'd like to make this process run in the background (but not the actual munt.exe process that gets opened). In other words, I want to hide the CMD window that appears.

Edit: Based on Deepesh's suggestion, I now have the following:

```
goto :Munt

:LoopStart
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq dosbox.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "dosbox.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0"
goto :LoopStart
taskkill /F /IM munt.exe
goto :EOF

:Munt
@echo off
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq munt.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "munt.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" goto :LoopStart
cd "Sound\VST MIDI Synth\MT-32 VST\"
start /min "" munt.exe
ping -n 2 -w 1000 127.0.0.1 >nul
goto :LoopStart
```

However, the problem is that the program that launches this batch file waits until the batch file has exited before launching dosbox.exe. So the batch file never sees dosbox.exe running and terminates before dosbox.exe has a chance to run. So, is there a way to exit the batch file, but continue to run it, if that makes any sense?

Comment: Enclose your code in a while loop. Check again and again if dosbox is running. If not, kill the process munt.exe and exit.

Comment: ok, by reading what you require and looking at the code, it does not seem legit. Firstly, why are you pinging localhost? is this a delay? if so, rather use `timeout /t 10` Then Let me see if I get this. You want to check that both dosbox and mund is running, if dosbox is dead, then stop mund and restart mund? or stop mund, restart dosbox and then restart mund?

Answer (score 1):

So here is the deal. To loop constantly and check that dosbox is running, you would need something like this. If dosbox is dropped, it will kill mund.

```
@echo off

:LoopStart
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq dosbox.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "dosbox.exe">NULL
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto :LoopStart
taskkill /F /IM munt.exe
goto :EOF
```

that will however loop nonstop and no delays are in place. so perhaps you want to only check it every few seconds, then do:

```
@echo off

:LoopStart
timeout /t 5
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq dosbox.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "dosbox.exe">NULL
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto :LoopStart
taskkill /F /IM munt.exe
goto :EOF
```

I am not 100% sure on the second portion though, do you want to ensure that mund.exe is running, as long as dosbox is running? If so, then this will suffice.

```
@echo off
:LoopStart
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq dosbox.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "dosbox.exe">NULL
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto :Munt
taskkill /F /IM munt.exe
goto :EOF

:Munt
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq munt.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "munt.exe">NULL
if %ERRORLEVEL% ==  0  goto :LoopStart
cd "Sound\VST MIDI Synth\MT-32 VST\"
start /min munt.exe
timeout /t 5
goto :LoopStart
:EOF
```

So to better explain this process. the script is checking for dosbox.exe, if it runs, it will pass to :munt to check if munt is running, if yes, it goes back and checks for dosbox in a loop. If however dosbox is not running will it kill munt. also, if dosbox is running but munt is not, it will start munt.

As for running it in the background, there are 2 ways. Setup a scheduled task to run the batchfile in a minimized form.

but it is best if you just create a VB script to run the file hidden for you.

You would need to add your batch file path and save the file with a VBS extention. this is then run which will call your batch file in a hidden mode.

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "C:\wordkingdir\mybatchfile.bat" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The below is a Batch program that creates a vbs script to Monitor a Process, than takes action to end the process.

In order to have it kill the specific process, Create a Batchfile with the Appropriate TASKKILL parameters to end that process and insert the Filepath where indicated.

Insert the Process to Monitor where Indicated.

With the exception of when you First launch the batch, The batch will remain Silent, and when the Taskkill batch is Launched, that too will run silent.
The VBS will relaunch the batch, effectively renewing the vbs for continuous monitoring.
The Message Box will notify you when the process you were monitoring ended - Replace the message to suit the process.

```
@ECHO OFF

(
ECHO Set objWMIService = GetObject ("winmgmts:"^)
ECHO Set proc = objWMIService.ExecQuery("select * from Win32_Process Where Name='Process To Moniter.exe'"^)
ECHO DO while proc.count ^> 0
ECHO Set proc = objWMIService.ExecQuery("select * from Win32_Process Where Name='Process To Moniter.exe'"^)
ECHO if proc.count ^< 1 then exit do
ECHO wscript.sleep 2000
ECHO loop
ECHO Set WshShell=createobject("wscript.shell"^)
ECHO WshShell.run "Pathway\Name of Batch File With Neseccary Taskkill.bat", 0, false
ECHO WshShell.run "%~0", 0, false
) >%TEMP%\MonitorEXE.vbs

Start %TEMP%\MonitorEXE.vbs

mshta vbscript:msgbox("Monitoring Process XYZ",0,"Notification")(window.close)

exit
```

This is adaptable to many situations where you want to take actions or a series of actions when a given process ends.
One thing of note - the Delay scripted in is highly recommended to reduce CPU usage.